# Why does my CSS code not work? It is linked correctly but the style rules just dont apply at all

Tags: html, css, server

I am just learning to code right now using an online course and I already set up a server and brought a test website online just to test out how it actually looks in the browser. Unfortunately, my CSS just doesn't work although I have uploaded both the index.html and style.css file in the same folder in public-HTML on my server. I have linked the CSS stylesheet correctly I think but it just doesn't work for some reason. This is what it looks like, it does not make any sense at all:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>home</title>

</head>

<body>

    <header>

    <h1 class = "brand">(coming soon)</h1>
    <h3 class = "brand">-Websites, presenting your company to the world-</h3>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./Codecademy/index">Playing around with coding course</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="prices">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="team">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    </header>

    <main>

      <h1>Elegant Interactive Websites</h1>
      <img src="Media/Website_image.jpeg" alt="" style = "width: 500px; height: 300px;">
      <h1>Beautiful Graphic Design</h1>
      <img src="Media/GraphicDesign_image.png" alt="" style = "width: 500px; height: 300px;">
      <h1>Seamless Animations</h1>
      <img src="Media/Animation.jpeg" alt="" style = "width: 500px; height: 300px;">
      <h1>Reliable Databases</h1>
      <img src="Media/Data base.jpeg" alt="" style = "width: 500px; height: 300px;">

    </main>

  <footer>
      <p>Code written in HTML, (some CSS) and JavaScript</p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my CSS code:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
  }

a {
    color: red;
}

.brand{
    color: red;
    font-size: 300px;
    font-family: cursive;
    background-color: black;
}

h1{
    color: red;
    font-size: 300px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Are the `css` and `html` files in the same directory? The `<link ... href="style.css">` states that they must be.

Comment: No repro ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-dawn-91uuy?file=/index.html

Comment: Use your browser's dev-tools to inspect the elements and see what styles have been applied. Also check for any errors in the _Console_ and _Network_ panels

Comment: It seems that your `HTML` and `CSS` do not exist same directory. Please learn how to include external css in HTML file. e.g [link1](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)  OR [link2](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-get-started.php)

Answer (score -3):

If your `CSS` is one folder outside of current directory of your `HTML` then you might try linking it like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
```